# Implement Master/Detail in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, data-binding

I have 2 tables List,ListItem form relation one to many (one list has many list Items).
I want to implement master/detail view using ListBoxs and domain data sources.
The following is my XAML, but the problem the detail table (ListItem) does not display the value of the selected row in the Master table (List table).I bound the detail listbox (ListBoxValues) with SelectedItem property of the master listbox (ListBoxNames).

```
<riaControls:DomainDataSource AutoLoad="True" Height="0"  Name="listDomainDataSource" QueryName="GetListQuery" Width="0">
            <riaControls:DomainDataSource.DomainContext>
                <my:Rule_DBDomainContext />
            </riaControls:DomainDataSource.DomainContext>
        </riaControls:DomainDataSource >

<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="2" Height="600" >
                            <ListBox Name="ListBoxNames" Margin="82,0,20,0" Width="200"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding Data,ElementName=listDomainDataSource}">
                                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <StackPanel>
                                            <TextBlock Name="listNameTxt" Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay}"></TextBlock>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            </ListBox>
                            <ListBox Name="ListBoxValues" Margin="82,0,20,0" Width="200" ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItem.ListItem,ElementName=ListBoxNames}" >
                                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <StackPanel>
                                            <TextBlock Name="listValueTxt" Text="{Binding Item, Mode=TwoWay}"></TextBlock>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            </ListBox>

                        </StackPanel>
```

PS:

I did some debugging I found that the ListItem property in the List class has not been filled! I dont know why, it is always zero count,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it just add a new domaindatasource and bind its filter with master listbox selecteditem property as follows

```
<riaControls:DomainDataSource AutoLoad="True" Height="0"  Name="listItemsDomainDataSource" QueryName="GetListItemQuery" Width="0" FilterOperator="And">
            <riaControls:DomainDataSource.DomainContext>
                <my:Rule_DBDomainContext />
            </riaControls:DomainDataSource.DomainContext>
            <riaControls:DomainDataSource.FilterDescriptors>
                <riaControls:FilterDescriptor PropertyPath="ListId" Operator="IsEqualTo" Value="{Binding ElementName=ListBoxNames, Path=SelectedItem.id}" />
            </riaControls:DomainDataSource.FilterDescriptors>
        </riaControls:DomainDataSource >
```